# PLS-00231 for in procedure defined function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I looked up the problem but didn't find a solution. my problem is as follows

```
create or replace procedure GETINFO(
    pIVR OUT NUMBER
) IS
      FUNCTION IS_MASK_ALLOWED(
                pBusSeg IN NUMBER,
                pCHTPMask IN NUMBER
       )
       RETURN BOOLEAN
       IS
       BEGIN
             IF pCHTPMask > 0 THEN    
             ELSE RETURN TRUE;
             END IF;

       END;
BEGIN

      SELECT 1
      INTO pIVR 
      FROM DUAL
      WHERE IS_MASK_ALLOWED(1, 2)=TRUE;

END;
```

the compiler says that I can not use IS_MASK_ALLOWED in SQL statements

ORACLE 10g
PL/SQL developer 7.5

Comment: thanks everyone. i should've stated that this is not actual code. i put it just to show that i declare function is_mask_allowed inside procedure, and i also call is_mask_allowed inside procedure GETINFO. I ommited all exception handlers in question and general complexity of procedure

Comment: I tried to create function is_mask_allowed_tst outside GETINFO procedure. and I can use is_mask_allowed_tst in where clause inside GETINFO code. it is no big problem to create is_mask_allowed in package or the same schema as my procedure and call it freely. I was just curious how come that when I declare my fucntion inside a procedure I can't use it in SQL code(however I can use it everywhere  in procdure body)

Answer (score 4):

Oracle does not support boolean statements in SQL so using `True` will not work. Try `select 1 from dual where True = True` to confirm.

Secondly if you're not allowing anyone to access `is_mask_allowed` outside your procedure and that's all it does then you can do this  `pIVR := 1`. which'll have the same result as your code ( procedure and function ). Personally if this is somewhere near all they do I'd have everything in the same procedure.

If you're missing some information in `is_mask_missing`, that `then` with nothing after it maybe then your package will error on `no_data_found` as there is the possibility of `select 1 from dual where 1 = 0`, which returns nothing.

If you do want `is_mask_allowed` to be accessed outside your procedure it would be easiest to put it in a package. As you can't use a boolean I've used a binary, where 0 represents false and 1 true

```
create or replace package my_package is

   function is_mask_allowed ( pBusSeg IN NUMBER
                            , pCHTPMask IN NUMBER
                            )  RETURN NUMBER;

   procedure get_info ( pIVR out NUMBER );

end my_package;
/
show error

create or replace package body my_package is

   function is_mask_allowed ( pBusSeg IN NUMBER
                            , pCHTPMask IN NUMBER
                            )  RETURN NUMBER is

   begin

      if pCHTPMask > 0 THEN
         -- do something
         return 0
      else return 1
      end if;

   end is_mask_allowed;

  -----------------------------------

   procedure getinfo( pIVR OUT NUMBER ) IS

   begin

       if is_mask_allowed(1,2) = 1 then
          pIVR := 1;
       else
          pIVR := -- something else;
       end if;

   end getinfo;

end my_package;
/
show error
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your is_mask_allowed function into a package to use it in SQL, and you should return something other than a boolean (perhaps a number) from the function and test for that, so your SQL is something more like:

```
select my_pkg.is_mask_allowed(1, 2) into pIVR from dual;
```

Here is a recent discussion in the Oracle forums on the same error:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2319500